# Ruby console - can't initialize a class with variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby console.  I start it by using `Rails console` and then do require 'path to my file' which works fine.

The file looks like this:

```
module App
  module Tools
    module Pollers
      class Kpi
        attr_reader :start_time,:stop_time

        def initialize(start_time,stop_time)
          @start_time = start_time
          @stop_time = stop_time
        end

        def create_social_audiences
        ....
```

So what I do is declare the stop and start time like this in the console

```
var end_date = new Date(2012, 7, 1);
var start  = new Date(2012, 5, 1);
```

and then I try to call .new on this file and get this error

```
>> kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
    from (irb):7:in `initialize'
    from (irb):7:in `new'
    from (irb):7
>>
```

but the weird part is that if I do this command which attempts to pass the variables it works:

```
>> kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new(start , end_date)
=> #<App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi:0x11489e198 @start_time=nil, @stop_time=nil>
```

but then when I try to do set the varialbes to anything other than nil I get errors that initialize is a private method:

```
?> kpi.initialize(start, end_date)
NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for #<App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi:0x11489e198>
    from (irb):15
```

Any thoughts on what might be happening wrong here?

Thanks!!

Comment: You shouldn't call `initialize` method directly.

This constructor is called by Ruby when you invoke a `new` on the class.

Moreover, since `@start_time` and `@stop_time` are declared as readonly attributes, the shouldn't be modified on an instance already created as you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti hi Andrea, yeah I was confused about that, but in any case, the problem seems to be that it is initializing the dates with nil values.  Would you know why that happens? I think that might be a part of the problem.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `nil` values!

Comment: @x3ro but how do I get the date varialbes to be set to anything that isn't nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call the class initializer after the class has been instantiated (and you cannot from outside of the class itself, given that it has private visibility).

The following does not work because you have an initializer with two parameters, therefore you also must pass those:

```
kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new
```

---

This works because the initializer is called when the class is being constructed (the `initialize` method is always invoked when you create a new instance using `new`):

```
kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new(start , end_date)
```

---

Finally, the following does not work (no matter what values start/end_date hold) because, as I explained earlier, the initializer of a class is private in ruby:

```
 kpi.initialize(start, end_date) # Breaks!
```

If you want to modify these variables after constructing the class, create a method for that:

```
def initialize(start, end)
    set_time(start_end)
end

def set_time(start, end)
    @start_time = start
    @end_time = end
end
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. What I am really confused about is that is I do new(start, end_date) then I would expect the object would have those dates already set.  So if I do kps.some_other_function it should be able to use the set date variables...no? But they seem to be getting set to nil instead of the values I am trying to pass to the date parameters.

Comment: Yes, the dates should be set after calling the initializer. Are you sure that the variables you are passing are actually different from nil? At least the following does work (and should be what you are doing too, according to the code you've posted): http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/6c9a9

Comment: yes it should work :) But you see in the code I pasted above I initialize the date variables, and when I pass them to the new variable, they show up as nil.  You can see that happen right in the question I pasted.

Comment: What I am saying is that, from the code that you've posted in the question, I am assuming that you are actually passing `nil` values to  `new()`. Try to print them right before `new` is invoked to see which values they have. Also, whats with the `var` keyword in `var end_date = new Date(2012, 7, 1);`? There is no such thing as `var` in Ruby!

Comment: ah I think you pointed me to where the real issue is - there was no error on those var declarations. Its a JavaScript syntax for mongo that I confused in there :)

Comment: thank you very much - with your help I was able to make it work.  Much much appreciated :)